# One form field throughout two DIVS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way i can have one form field set through out two divs? Basically ill have one div float left, one div float right, and through those two divs ill have a few form fields spread out. How would i approach this or should i just do it like below?

```
<FORM>
<DIV float left>
...fields...
</DIV>
<DIV float right>
...more fields ... and submit ...
</DIV>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Have you tried your own suggestion to see how it looks/works?

Comment: Not yet im going to try coding something and apply it soon, just was curious for my self, wasnt sure if it would actually work.

Comment: Don't know any other way to get this to you, but earlier you asked a question about Images as radio button, but then deleted your question. Wanted to let you know I have a solution that you should be able to adapt to your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/dGWJp/27/

Comment: Wow awesome this is perfect better than the last one, but i have one issue. I am using jquery 1.3.2min for something which seems to be conflicting with 1.7.2. Any idea how to go around this?

Comment: Maybe ill just have it all load of 1.7.2 ill try that.

Comment: Also is there a way to make each and every single one of them have its own unqique image and clicked image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example structure should work fine

Comment: Is it a good structure to follow or is there something better and cleaner?

Comment: I would personally follow the same/similar structure if i was to produce this. I may use `<fieldset>` tags instead of `<div>`s but ultimately the same. If there's something cleaner I'd be up for hearing it.

Comment: What exactly are fieldset tags?

Comment: "The <fieldset> tag is used to group related elements in a form." - W3Schools. It has almost identical properties to a DIV